# Action hook in Ember.js

Tags: ember.js, action

I would like to use a Mixin to intercept a list of actions (before the specific action function is executed on the controller, route or component). Is there any way I can do this?

The code would look something like:

```
App.MyMixin = Em.Mixin.create({

    interceptorFunction : function(actionName){
       console.log('intercepted action: ' + actionName);

    }   

});

App.TheInterceptedComponent = Em.Component.extend(App.MyMixin, {
     actions : {
         sampleAction : function() {
              console.log('sampleAction std handler called');
         }
     }
});
```

Looking for a way to have intereptorFunction called before sampleAction.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here is a working demo](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/qoror/1/edit) where the handler in the mixin is executed first after the handler in the controller is called. To call the controllers handler, we need to call `this._super();`.

```
App.MyMixin = Em.Mixin.create({
  actions: {
    actionHandler: function() {
      alert('Handled In Mixin');
      this._super();
    }
  }
});

App.IndexController = Em.ObjectController.extend({
    actions: {
      actionHandler: function() {
        alert('Handled In Controller');
      }
    }
  }, 
  App.MyMixin
);
```

Comment: Great, works just fine. Didn't think about reordering the arguments. Thank you